# How do I create a calendar in code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to create an asp.net ajax calendar like [this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx), but entirely in code-behind. How do I do it?

**Edit:** I only want to add the js code to the page in code-behind (eg: not in the markup)

**Edit_2:** I need this because I create a textbox control in a template class and want to create the calendar there (for use with the textbox)

Comment: Rather depends on what you mean by "entirely in code-behind" as ajax by definition involves code in the client. That said, those tools and others are design time components to do the Ajax heavy lifting for you so the work you do is just a combination of work at design time and in code behind at run time.

Fundamentally that question is too vague - you can certainly add the necessary javascript to the page at runtime from the code behind, but to provide a useful answer we need to know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET ajax calendar you refer to is an extender, so in theory you could add it to your textbox at runtime in the code-behind. See the example below, the placeholder is vital!

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, can you give us a better idea of the need as there may be a better solution.

**Simple page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"><asp:scriptmanager runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Place1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AjaxControlToolkit;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalendarExtender myCalExt = new CalendarExtender();
            myCalExt.TargetControlID = "TextBox1";
            Place1.Controls.Add(myCalExt);
        }
    }
}
```